# Paging results in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, paging

I am trying to find a solution in asp.net in order to achieve paging of data so
1) Application does not have to connect to DB on each page index change, in order to retrieve either entire set or just a paged set of results
2) Do not want to store results in Viewstate or Session

For large result sets, I was thinking of storing key values (ID, rownumber) in a result set (array, json) and then populate additional row information on row binding.

Is there a way to do it in asp.net, or I need to consider jQuery for this scenario.

Comment: Is this webforms or MVC?  If webforms - the MVC tag should be removed as they are very different implementations on .NET web applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Application does not have to connect to DB on each page index change, in order to retrieve either entire set or just a paged set of results

You need to cache your results. For example:

Example:

#### Caching Approach 1

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsd"
        SelectCommand="select * from jobs"
        SelectCommandType="Text"
        DataSourceMode="DataSet"
        ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings: PUBSConnectionString %>"
        CacheDuration="30"
        EnableCaching="true"
    >
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="sdsd" DataTextField="job_desc" DataValueField="job_id">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

#### Caching Approach 2

You could always cache your results in code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        IEnumerable<employee> res = Enumerable.Empty<employee>();

        if (this.Cache["emp"] == null)
        {
            res = this.GetEmployeesFromDatabase();
            this.Cache["emp"] = res;
        }
        else
        {
            res = this.GetEmployeesFromCache();
        }

        this.grv.DataSource = res;
        this.grv.DataBind();
    }
}

protected IEnumerable<employee> GetEmployeesFromDatabase()
{
    // go to your database to get the objects
    return Enumerable.Empty<employee>();
}

protected IEnumerable<employee> GetEmployeesFromCache()
{
    return this.Cache["emp"] as IEnumerable<employee>;
}
```

Keep in mind that the returned object must to be a `DataSet` or `DataTable` in order to add sorting capabilities to your cache results

> 2) Do not want to store results in Viewstate or Session

Again you need to use cache

> Is there a way to do it in asp.net, or I need to consider jQuery for this scenario.

I don't see how jQuery (by itself) can help you with your requirement, I mean if you use AJAX posts, you would improve the perceived performance of your current page, but that won't help you with the connections to the database unless you use caching

Comment: Your two caching approaches are being cached per thread of for the entire application? jQuery can pull data (example json from from web service) and store it as a javascript object. Looping trough that object would dynamically create table, list or something else. This is completely different approach, unloading the server (cache) and shifting load to client. I would have to test speed between your caching idea and jQuery.

Comment: Another thing is if 1000 users would make a search based on 10 params (not identical in 99%) that would be 1000 cached results for just one search per user. This does not sound promising in case of increased visitors.

Comment: mm I can think in one negative approach from your jQuery approach, (there are also negative impacts in my recommendation like scalability issues since you would be using your memory server to store your results). In your case, you would be hitting the database every time a user requests your page, on the other hand, there wowuld be only one hit, the first user

Comment: _that would be 1000 cached results for just one search per user._ That would happen only if you use page caching (it's different to my recommendations but still an option), in that case, the whole page (or just a part if you use user controls) would be cached, which means the rendered markup would be cached. In my recommendations, the query results would be cached, not the whole page. The benefits of using page caching is that your request won't be processed (ergo, no database hit).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether it covers all your requirement but for paging their is [PagedDataSource Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.aspx)

Encapsulates the paging-related properties of a data-bound control (such as DataGrid, GridView, DetailsView, and FormView) that allow it to perform paging. This class cannot be inherited.

Else I would suggest you look in to the [JqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Answer (score 1):

For paged datasets you're generally have 2 options:

- if you're expecting a small result set (i.e. limit search results to 500 rows or less) then     using viewstate is perfectly acceptable. I personally prefer to avoid using session for storing request level data

  - If you're expecting a large result set then you'll need a paged data source. You can write a stored proc that returns a paged dataset (i.e. passing a page index/page size) or use any of the ORM's (ENTITY framework or LINQ TO SQL). Either support paging with take(n) and skip(n).

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1699/sql-server-stored-procedures-to-page-large-tables-or-queries/

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Regardless of how you render the data (jQuery/ajax or server control) you still have to either get the whole result set in one shot and cache it for subsequent requests (json array or viewstate), or you need a data source the supports paging. If you're concerned with performance then a paged data source is the way to go (the EF example will work just fine for webforms as well, just use your event handlers instead of action methods in mvc).

Comment: is it possible to cache data for asp.net application on client as an javascript or json array and then reuse it in .net code?